# Python два ключа у значения в словаре

Tags: python, while, dict

Нужна помощь c программой, которая запрашивает у пользователя названия фильмов и главных действующих лиц, пока в названии фильма не появится пустая строка. Название фильма становится ключом к словарю, а главное действующее лицо становится значением. После ввода пустой строки программа запрашивает имя актера и распечатывает фильмы этого актера. Ниже приведен пример того, как работает программа:

film name (stop if no value): Mad max

Actor name: Mel Gibson

film name (stop if no value): Batman

Actor name: Christian Bale

film name (stop if no value): Braveheart

Actor name: Mel Gibson

film name (stop if no value):

Give actor's name, which has a films : Mel Gibson

Mad Max

Braveheart

У меня как раз не получается вывести оба фильма, где участвует один актёр.

Мой код:

```
movies = {}
while True:
    film=input("film name (stop if no value): ")
    if len(film)==0:
        for actor, film in movies.items():                
            # movies = actor +'\n'+ film
            print("Give actor's name, which has a films :",film, "\n" + actor )
            break
    actor=input("Actor name: ")
    
    movies[film]=actor
    
print(movies)
```

Comment: а где вы в вашем коде пытаетесь что-то искать и выводить?

Comment: ```if len(film)==0:``` то есть название фильма пусто?

Comment: я имею в виду про актера?

Comment: Да, если строка пустая. то выходит последняя строка из примера, где написано имя актера и все введенные до этого фильмы. Введенные до того как пустая строка принята к исполнению. 
Код написан в профессиональном плане неверно, я это понимаю.  Он работает до какого то момента, мне просто хотелось бы понять что не так в нём и как исправить. Спасибо

Comment: тут нет кода кода, который ищет и выводит фильмы. Это и надо исправлять.

Comment: Программа в данный момент выводит только запросы. да нет именно кода который ищет, я не могу понять как исправить код. Если это слишком сложно, тогда можно ничего не писать спасибо.

Comment: это не сложно. непонятно, почему вы даже не попробовали

Comment: Зачем вы пишете чего не знаете? Вам не сложно написать гадость или оскорбить. Суть форума в чем? Вас никто не просит учить. 
У меня написан код да неверный, но я 4 часа уже не могу сделать. Интерес уже просто в том, чтобы понять как это работает. Если нечего по существу сказать не надо ветку спамить. 


У меня на выходе выходит : 

Give actor's name, which has a films : Mel Gibson

Mad Max.

Как второй фильм добавить _? Вот что я хотел узнать и все...А не то кто я и что я. Спасибо

Comment: Вам и говорят, что тут нет кода, который хотя бы пытается делать то, что вам нужно. Поэтому и непонятно, что тут исправлять, потому что исправлять нечего.

Comment: Вам виднее.  Удачи вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для примера:

```
d = {}
while True:
    movie = input('title>> ')
    if movie:
        d[movie] = d.get(movie, []) + [input('actor>> ')]
    else:
        actor = input('search>> ')
        print(*[k for k,v in d.items() if actor in v], sep='\n')
        break
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Нашелся человек, кто просто наглядно объяснил, на примере как такие задачи решаются. Спасибо вам.